# Cannot run program makefile when compiling a c++ program with NetBeans and MinGW gcc

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, makefile

I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello" program on Windows 7 x64:

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And getting an error in the NetBeans IDE when compiling:

> CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 126ms)

```
D:\GDrive\CS\Cpp\NetBeans_Cpp\TNB_cpp\Tut1_10_HelloWorld\Makefile -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o
Cannot run program "D:\GDrive\CS\Cpp\NetBeans_Cpp\TNB_cpp\Tut1_10_HelloWorld\Makefile" (in directory "D:\GDrive\CS\Cpp\NetBeans_Cpp\TNB_cpp\Tut1_10_HelloWorld"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

COMPILE FILE FAILED (exit value -2, total time: 16ms)
```

My PATH env variable looks like this:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;F:\Program_Files\JDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;F:\Program_Files\MinGW\bin;F:\Program_Files\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;
```

The last two varibles being probably the most important since they pertain to the MinGW. My ideas is that something is missing in the PATH, but maybe its not where the problem hiddes.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like the Makefile is broken.

Comment: You're trying to run a program called 'Makefile' -- that's probably not right.  Makefiles are generally run by a program called `make`.

Comment: I basically used a default makefile generated by the NetBeans when creating a project. Maybe it is not broken but was never set up properly in the first place? I just saw that creating make files is a lesson in itself - is there a way to run c++ without them in netbeans with MinGW ?

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius Post your Makefile, it can give us a hint. Go to project properties ->  Build: take a look in 'Configuration Type', just to make sure you are building an application and not a library, for instance. PS. Go to Project->Properties->Linker:  What is in the 'output' field?

Comment: @moskito-x could you please add this as an answer so I can accept it. You identified it correclty./

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if some settings are wrong.
Look at your Netbeans settings : Toolchain : `Make Command`

looking after one of the files.

- make.exe
- mingw32-make.exe.

In the directories, for example,

- c:\msys\1.0\bin
- c:\MinGW\bin

goto -> options -> c/c++ -> Build Tools
and check if the settings match this

[image]